# Refactor regular for loop into angular.forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I'm new to js and stuck with refactoring following code:

```
for (var i = vm.notActiveOffers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                for (var j = 0; j < vm.activeOffers.length; j++) {
                    if (vm.notActiveOffers[i] && (vm.notActiveOffers[i].offerId === vm.activeOffers[j].offerId)) {
                        vm.notActiveOffers.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

After refactor:

```
angular.forEach(vm.notActiveOffers, function(notActiveOffer) {
                angular.forEach(vm.activeOffers, function(activeOffer) {
                    if(notActiveOffer && (notActiveOffer.offerId === activeOffer.offerId)) {
                        vm.notActiveOffers.splice(_.indexOf(vm.notActiveOffers, notActiveOffer), 1);
                    }
                })
            });
```

The refactored version doesn't work as expected and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Can you give us the `vm.notActiveOffers` content? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: @Bavi Gurunath it wont work since you are trying to find the position of an object inside an array. You need to write your own custom function for this.

Comment: thats just refactoring to slowness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya, you cannot remove an item from the array while iterating it.

you can use remove fn from lodash.

Check if below code works for you.

```
angular.forEach(activeOffers, function(activeOffer) {    
    _.remove(notActiveOffers, function(notActiveOffer) {
        return notActiveOffer.offerId === activeOffer.offerId;
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you. It generates a hash table for all activ offers and use it for filtering the not active offers array.

```
var activeOffers = Object.create(null);

vm.activeOffers.forEach(function (a) {
    activeOffers[a.offerId] = true;
});

vm.notActiveOffers = vm.notActiveOffers.filter(function (a) {
    return !activeOffers[a.offerId];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing items from an array while still iterating it - this is very error-prone and should be avoided.

The difference between the 2 code snippets you have posted is in the order in which array elements are visited. In the first scenario the array is iterated from the last to the first element and you are removing elements from the its rear (elements you have already traversed). In the second case you are removing elements from the array front and thus possibly not traversing some array elements.

A refactored version should not delete elements from an array while still iterating it, I think.